# Why do Esperantists use more "x" instead of "h", which is in the Esperanto alphabet?

Tags: esperanto-speakers, spelling

I was wondering why some Esperantists use the *x* system (it isn't in the Esperanto alphabet) instead of *h* (which is in the Esperanto alphabet). Should not it be promoted to *h*, regularized, or something like that?

Comment: Probably _because_ ‘x’ is not in the Esperanto alphabet, so there is never ambiguity.

Comment: Now I am wondering if you are asking this because of a misunderstanding. Neither the x nor the h are used as real letters, they are just used as an alternative to typing the letters ĥ ŝ ĝ ĉ ĵ and ŭ in cases where that is difficult. It wouldn’t make sense to consider x a letter of the alphabet any more than you would consider ^ a letter. It doesn’t have its own pronunciation.

Comment: 'H' IS a letter in esperanto so there is the potential for ambiguity ('chashundo' could be 'ĉashundo' or 'ĉaŝundo'). Since 'x' isn't a letter there is no ambiguity. It's pretty simple. If you use 'h' you're adding ambiguity to a language intended to be free of ambiguity.

Answer (score 10):

Two arguments I have encountered for preferring "x" to "h":

- Because it is not an existing letter in the Esperanto alphabet, automated conversion is possible, e.g. *sx* could be unambiguously converted to *ŝ*.  By contrast, even if combinations like *-sh-*  are rare, they could occur in compound words e.g. *dishaki*, so *sh* cannot be reliably converted to *ŝ* (similarly *senchava*, *flughaveno*, etc).
- Because it is so near the end of the alphabet, it is almost always the case that a naive lexical sorting will achieve correct alphabetical order.  So for example, a naive sorting would put *sxi* after *sorto* (which would be correct, because *ŝi* comes after *sorto*), but would put *shi* before *sorto*.  This only fails when a letter to which an accent could be applied is followed by *z*; for example a naive sort would misorder *uxato* (*ŭato*) and *uzi*, but such occurrences are very rare.

Comment: I always used the first point as explanation of why it's better to use *x*, but I see the second point is valid too.

Answer (score 3):

People tend to prefer the x-system exactly because it isn’t a letter in the Esperanto alphabet, so there is no risk of confusion. For example if you see the word *flughaveno* you might first ask yourself ‘what is a fluĝo?’ before recognising the word. With the X-system there is no such ambiguity.

These days the hats are pretty widely supported in browsers and most software, and it’s usually not too difficult to install some software to help type them, so both systems are less and less common.

Comment: It's actually so easy today, that a user who hasn't solved the issue for their device is often looked at with a pity.

Comment: The x-sistem is also more practical when alphabetizing a list in a computer, for example file names. Hatted letters always follow their plain siblings and x (unlike h) comes after most esperanto-letters in the English alphabet. Compare how segho/segxo is placed in a list with segilo.

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro, if you do that, you are alphabetizing Esperanto wrong. _La ĉapelitaj_ letters are sorted separately i.e. first all c words, then all ĉ and so on.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas I think alani's answer explains it in more detail. In most cases words will be correctly sorted.

Comment: "Most cases" is not enough ,say, for word list in a vocabulary. The alphabetical order should be unambiguous. See the project [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) for **exact** alphabetical orders.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the more natural **h** (ch, sh) and such a notation was proposed as alternative for Esperanto letters.
In the newer times the alternative with **x** was introduced with as argument: *automatic translation*. As `chashundo` was ambiguous `chas-hundo`. Try reta-vortaro.de with x's.

It is a subcultural phenomenon I think. Like accented characters are very dear to the language users. German without umlauts, a French *café* without accent droite, Spanish ñ. Even English borrowing *façade*.

Both are legal and understood. So use h with hyphens (chas-hundo) if it pleases.
Meanwhile I am content to use x too.

By the way for smartphones one can install Esperanto support for the letters.

Comment: the point is using 'chashundo' instead of cx/sx etc; introduces kind of the same problem that Japanese has. The word 'し' (shi) can be 'four' (四) or 'death' (死). If it is typed in hiragana instead of kanji (as it would be for elementary school students) you can't tell the difference. That has actually resulted in a superstition in Japan where it's considered a bad omen to give somebody four of anything.

Answer (score -3):

The x-system is a reform attempt to Esperanto. Yes, it also should be changed to the h-system, because the cases in which the x-system is used are often the same cases that the h-system can be used, such as in urls.

An example is in url paths:

(h-system) https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/serchilo.html
vs (x-system) https://tubaro.aperu.net/?sp=v&ord=temp_ad&lingv=eo&kategori=cxio&pagx=2.

[In the h-system, the breve is removed so the ´ŭ´ is stored as ´u´.](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html) The x-system reformists think this transformation would cause problems with ambiguity, which is why they formed it. However this thought is not true; ´ŭ´ and ´u´ are distinguishable by letter name: ŭo ≠ u.

For reference, here is the alphabet of Esperanto from the ekzercaro in the Fundamento de Esperanto:

> [Nomoj de la literoj: a, bo, co, ĉo, do, e, fo, go, ĝo, ho, ĥo, i, jo, ĵo, ko, lo, mo, no, o, po, ro, so, ŝo, to, ***u, ŭo,*** vo, zo.](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/ekzercaro.html)

So one can store each Esperanto letter by their name *in* the h-system, to fully capture and save Esperanto text *by* the h-system. For example: "aŭtismulo" would be stored in the h-system as [a uo to i so mo u lo o].